# Unable to access Kowl web UI running on docker on mac

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-for-mac

I have a macbook and I have locally running zookeeper and kafka instances on port 2181 and 9092 respectively. I am able to bring up [kowl](https://github.com/cloudhut/kowl) locally using the following command mentioned in the git repo

```
kowl % docker run -p 8081:8081 -e KAFKA_BROKERS=host.docker.internal:19092 quay.io/cloudhut/kowl:master
```

I see that the app is running successfully on docker, please find the logs attached below

> {"level":"info","msg":"config filepath is not set, proceeding with
> options set from env variables and flags"}
> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-03-23T17:48:25.475Z","msg":"started
> Kowl","version":"master","git_sha":"5ff6e3c4dea98737b661186519eb310f2a898d06","built":"2022-03-09T15:34:53Z"}
> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-03-23T17:48:25.478Z","msg":"connecting to
> Kafka seed brokers, trying to fetch cluster metadata"}
> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-03-23T17:48:25.489Z","msg":"successfully
> connected to kafka
> cluster","advertised_broker_count":1,"topic_count":2,"controller_id":0,"kafka_version":"v3.0"}
> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-03-23T17:48:25.489Z","msg":"creating Kafka
> connect HTTP clients and testing connectivity to all clusters"}
> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-03-23T17:48:25.489Z","msg":"tested Kafka
> connect cluster
> connectivity","successful_clusters":0,"failed_clusters":0}
> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-03-23T17:48:25.490Z","msg":"successfully
> create Kafka connect service"}
> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-03-23T17:48:25.549Z","msg":"Server
> listening on address","address":"[::]:8080","port":8080}

I am unable to access the application from the browser at https://localhost:8081. I tried accessing this via the container IP using *docker inspect* as well as *host.docker.internal* ip but to no avail. I recently moved to a mac, is it a known issue ? Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Kafka is running directly on your Mac, why not run Kowl there too? What advantage is there to using Docker here? More importantly, why are you using `8081:8081` when the logs are clearly saying its running on port 8080?

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use [the exact command from the documentation](https://github.com/cloudhut/kowl#kafka-is-running-locally)?

Comment: @OneCricketeer

Thank you for your replies. I have quite a lot of web apps running locally and so I went ahead with the docker route for this application, as well as needed a UI app which can be deployed on the same cluster where the faka and other apps are

As you mentioned, specifying the right port mapping fixed it

docker run -p 8081:8080 -e KAFKA_BROKERS=host.docker.internal:19092 quay.io/cloudhut/kowl:master

Answer (score 3):

the following command worked, I had the ports mixed up

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 -e KAFKA_BROKERS=host.docker.internal:19092 quay.io/cloudhut/kowl:master
```

now I am able to access the ui at http://localhost:8081/